# Lost the connection to database when using switch statment

Tags: c++, database, qt, qt4, switch-statement

I have `stackedwidget` with multiple pages, at page one, I check the connection, page two, I check the availability of user, and so on for the rest of page(I have five), basically, other pages depend in the first page, if the connection failed or not, my problem is about other pages, even the connection made with out any errors, the second page can't made its query, I am getting this error:

```
QSqlQuery::prepare: database not open
```

My slot:

```
void ConfSetup::setNextPage()
{
    int currentIndex = ui->stackedWidget->currentIndex();

    switch(currentIndex)
     {
       case 1:
        ui->stackedWidget->setCurrentIndex(currentIndex + 1);
       break;

       case 2:
        db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
        db.setDatabaseName("mysql");
        db.setHostName(ui->serverEdit->text());
        db.setPort(ui->portEdit->text().toInt());
        db.setUserName(ui->userEdit->text());
        db.setPassword(ui->passwordEdit->text());

        if(!db.open())
         {
           QMessageBox::critical(0, trUtf8("Fail to login"), trUtf8("Wrong user or password"));
         }
        else
          ui->stackedWidget->setCurrentIndex(currentIndex + 1);

       break;

       case 3:
        query.prepare("SELECT user FROM user WHERE user=:user");
        query.bindValue(":user", ui->userDbEdit->text());
        query.exec();

        if(query.numRowsAffected() == 1)
           QMessageBox::critical(0, trUtf8("User exist"), trUtf8("This user already token"));
        else
           ui->stackedWidget->setCurrentIndex(currentIndex + 1);
       break;

       case 4:
        query.prepare("SELECT SCHEMA_NAME AS 'Database' FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA WHERE SCHEMA_NAME=:database");
        query.bindValue(":database", ui->dbNameEdit->text());
        query.exec();

        if(query.numRowsAffected() == 1)
           QMessageBox::critical(0, trUtf8("Fail to create database"), trUtf8("This database already exist"));
        else
           ui->stackedWidget->setCurrentIndex(currentIndex + 1);
       break;
     }
}
```

The connection:

```
connect(ui->nextButton0, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(setNextPage()));
connect(ui->nextButton1, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(setNextPage()));
//etc
```

Comment: where have you declared the variable 'db' ?

Comment: @Abhijith in `confsetup.h`, and the current file is `confsetup.cpp`.

Comment: I think you need to construct variable 'query' like this ...  query = new QSqlQuery ( db ).. have you done that ?

Comment: @Abhijith The error message gone now, but the query always return -1, even it is correct.

Comment: what does query.getLastError return ?

Comment: @Abhijith 
`qDebug() << query->lastError();`
Result:
`QSqlError(-1, "", "") `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation:

> Warning: You must load the SQL driver
>   and open the connection before a
>   QSqlQuery is created. Also, the
>   connection must remain open while the
>   query exists; otherwise, the behavior
>   of QSqlQuery is undefined.

So I have to declare `QSqlQuery query` variable at each `case` statment, now my problem solved.